# Como eu faço um update direto na pessoa logada?

Tags: php

Como eu faço um update direto na pessoa logada?

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF912.png)

```
public function logar(){
    $usuario_email = $this->input->post('usuario_email');
    $usuario_senha = $this->input->post('usuario_senha');
    $this->db->where('usuario_email',$usuario_email);
    $this->db->where('usuario_senha',$usuario_senha);
    $data['usuario'] = $this->db->get('usuario')->result();
    if(count($data['usuario'])==1){
        $dados['usuario_nome']=$data['usuario'][0]->usuario_nome;
        $dados['usuario_id']=$data['usuario'][0]->usuario_id;
        $dados['logado']=true;
        $this->session->set_userdata($dados);
        redirect(atividade);
        } else {
        redirect(atividade);
        }

}
    public function  sair(){
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('atividade');
    }
}


    public function cadastrar() {

    $data['usuario_nome'] = $this->input->post('usuario_nome');
    $data['usuario_sobrenome'] = $this->input->post('usuario_sobrenome');
    $data['usuario_email'] = $this->input->post('usuario_email');
    $data['usuario_senha'] = $this->input->post('usuario_senha');
    if ($this->db->insert('usuario',$data)) {
        redirect(atividade);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só você pegar o `id` na session que criou:

```
public function alterar($nome, $sobrenome, $email, $senha){
    $sql = "UPDATE tabela SET usuario_nome={$nome}, usuario_sobrenome={$sobrenome}, usuario_email={$email}, usuario_senha={$senha} WHERE usuario_id={$_SESSION['id']}"
}
```